# Creating a palindrome list with reverse()

Tags: python

I want to take a list `[0,1,2]` and turn it into `[0,1,2,2,1,0]`. Right now, I've got

```
r = list(mus)
r.reverse()
mus = mus + r
```

but it seems like there should be a better way. Can anyone come up with a good, pythonic one-liner?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like you might be in need of

```
mus.extend(reversed(mus))
```

Or if you simply need to iterate over this and not necessarily form the list, use

```
import itertools
for item in itertools.chain(mus, reversed(mus)):
    do_something...
```

Answer (score 2):

Just a few of the many ways to do this are:

1. m = l + reversed(l)
2. m = l + l[::-1]
3. l.extend(reversed(l))
4. l.extend(l[::-1])

The first two assign the output to a new list, and the second two update the list in place.  If I was being clever, I would probably use 2 or 4, but if I wanted there to be no mistake about what I was doing, then I would opt for 1 or 3.

Hope this helps.

Edit:
As pointed out in the comments, #1 doesn't work, as reversed returns an iterator.  You could make it work by changing it to:

m = l + list(reversed(l))

But I can't recommend it.  Go with 2 instead.

BTW, thanks for the correction and sorry for any confusion.

Comment: Your case 1 doesn't work. (`reversed` does not return a list.)